# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 (Is my stream the problem, or what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, flutter-test

My app is about the user choosing a level. Once he has done so, he will be redirected to the page corresponding to the level.

First I use a future, which determines the current userID and sets level in the document of the user in cloud firestore equal to 0 if no level has been selected yet. (I only do this so I can update {Level: 0} later.)

Once the Future has loaded, a StreamBuilder is played. And here begins my problem:

I try to record permanently with the StreamBuilder which level is stored by the user in Cloud Firestore.

[image]

Level:0 => then the stream displays a list in which you can select a level.

Level:1 => the StreamBuilder displays the appropriate page

Level:2 => the StreamBuilder displays the appropriate page
...

---

That’s the code I’ve been talking about:

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  User? user;
  late LevelService levelService;

  Future<void> standard() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    user = _auth.currentUser;
    levelService = LevelService(user!.uid);
    if (!(await levelService.checkIfLevelExists())) {
      return levelService.setLevel('level', 0);
    }
  }

  Map<String, bool> Level = {
    'Level 1': false,
    'Level 2': false,
    'Level 3': false,
    'Level 4': false,
    'Level 5': false,
    'Level 6': false
  };

  void toggleDone(String key) {
    setState(() {
      Level.update(key, (bool value) => !value);
    });
  }

  void select(key) {
    if (key == 'Level 1') {
      levelService.updateUser('Level', 1);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 2') {
      levelService.updateUser('Level', 2);
    }
    if (key == 'level 3') {
      levelService.updateUser('Level', 3);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 4') {
      levelService.updateUser('level', 4);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 5') {
      levelService.updateUser('Level', 5);
    }
    if (key == 'Level 6') {
      levelService.updateUser('level', 6);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 112, 192, 1),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: standard(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: levelService.getLevel(),
                    builder:
                        (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Level'] == 1) {
                          Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ToDo1F()));}
                        if (snapshot.data!.docs[0]['Level'] == 2) {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ToDo2F()));} else
                      return ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            );
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          itemCount: Level.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext, i) {
                            String key = Level.keys.elementAt(i);
                            return LevelItem(
                              key,
                              Level[key]!,
                              () => toggleDone(key),
                              () => select(key),
                            );
                          });
                      }
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    },
                  );
                }
              }));
    }
  }


class LevelItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String Level;
  final bool value;
  final Function toggleDone;
  final Function select;
  const LevelItem(this.Level, this.value, this.toggleDone, this.select);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
        value: value,
        title: Text(Level),
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          toggleDone();
          if (value == true) select();
        });
  }
}
```

And here is the stream that interacts with Firestore:

```
    class LevelService {
  String userID;
  LevelService(this.userID);


  final CollectionReference userTodos =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getLevel() {
    var level = userTodos.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
    level = level.where('Level', isEqualTo: 1-6);
    return level.snapshots();
  }
```

In Cloud firestore {Level: 1} is already created. However, I get the following error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve the problem?

Comment: you should remove your project id from the screenshot and flag for moderator action once you've done that so we can completely remove it from history